# How to get a Left Join on Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, join

I have this query with Join. This gives me an inner join. What I want to accomplish is a left join.
I tried using `DefaultIfEmpty()` but I couldn't get it to work. Perhaps I am putting it on the wrong part of the query.

Can anyone point me out to the right way of using `DefaultIfEmpty()`?

Below is my current query:

```
var AppList = (de.ComputerUserApplication)
                    .Where(CUA => CUA.EmployeeID == employeeID)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
                    .Join(de.ApplicationTypeMasters,
                        CUA => CUA.RecordType,
                        ATM => ATM.Code,
                        (CUA, ATM) => new ApplicationModel
                        {
                            ApplicationNo = CUA.ApplicationNo,
                            ApplicationCode = CUA.RecordType,
                            ApplicationTypeCode = "",
                            ApplicationName = ATM.Title + " - " + CUA.Description,
                            Status = CUA.Status
                        });
```

Also, I'm not quite sure if I have the correct query. if you may, below is my original query:

```
select Cua_ApplicationNo, Cua_Type_Rec, ATM_ApplicationTitle, Cua_Status  from ComputerUserApplication
left join ApplicationTypeMaster
    on Cua_Type_Rec = ATM_ApplicationCode
        where Cua_EmployeeID = 'someID'
```

Comment: @anon Putting it on a new line makes no difference at all

Comment: Yes. That's just for internal coding standards we have. What I need to know is how to use DefaultIfEmpty to achieve left outer join. It would be great if you can point me out what's actually wrong with how I used DefaultIfEmpty.

Comment: I believe `.DefaultIfEmpty` should be on the right table (`ApplicationTypeMasters`) rather than on your left table. That is, the line should read: `.Join(de.ApplicationTypeMasters.DefaultIfEmpty(),`

Comment: @Rob I still couldn't get it right. Maybe my problem is not with the getting the left join but on how I converted my original query. I'll update my question to include original query.

Comment: @Rob man your an angel. your solution did worked actually. Wasn't able to get the result I am getting earlier because of the inconsistencies on my data. got it working though. `.Join(de.ApplicationTypeMasters.DefaultIfEmpty()` did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [GroupJoin for an outer join](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/linq-groupjoin-and-join-differences); this will work assuming there's 0 or 1 matching ApplicationTypeMaster rows; if more, then you'd need to do a `DefaultIfEmpty` followed by `SelectMany`.

```
de.ComputerUserApplication
  .Where(x => x.EmployeeID == employeeID)
  .GroupJoin(
      de.ApplicationTypeMasters, 
      CUA => CUA.RecordType, 
      ATM => ATM.Code, 
      (CUA, ATM) => new ApplicationModel
      {
          ApplicationNo = CUA.ApplicationNo,
          ApplicationCode = CUA.RecordType,
          ApplicationTypeCode = "",
          ApplicationName = ATM.SingleOrDefault()?.Title + " - " + CUA.Description,
          Status = CUA.Status
      }
  );
```

If you don't know how many matching rows there are, then SelectMany will give you the equivalent results as SQL:

```
de.ComputerUserApplication
  .Where(x => x.EmployeeID == employeeID)
  .GroupJoin(
      de.ApplicationTypeMasters, 
      CUA => CUA.RecordType, 
      ATM => ATM.Code, 
      (x, y) => new { CUA = x, ATMs = y.DefaultIfEmpty() }
  ).SelectMany(x => x.ATMs.Select(ATM => new ApplicationModel
      {
         ApplicationNo = x.CUA.ApplicationNo,
         ApplicationCode = x.CUA.RecordType,
         ApplicationTypeCode = "",
         ApplicationName = ATM?.Title + " - " + x.CUA.Description,
         Status = x.CUA.Status
      }
  );
```

As an aside, this is one of the few times I prefer the query syntax (which does SelectMany without all the noise):

```
  from CUA in de.ComputerUserApplication
  join x in de.ApplicationTypeMasters on CUA.RecordType equals x.Code into g
  from ATM in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new ApplicationModel()
  {
     ApplicationNo = CUA.ApplicationNo,
     ApplicationCode = CUA.RecordType,
     ApplicationTypeCode = "",
     ApplicationName = ATM?.Title + " - " + CUA.Description,
     Status = CUA.Status
   };
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot. However, is there a specific reason why you prefer the other syntax?

Comment: This works well. I just had to change SingleOrDefault to FirstOrDefault. :)

Comment: @marijanluvlee - If you had to use a FirstOrDefault, I think that means that there's > 1 matching rows in ApplicationTypeMasters. In that case, you'd want to do a DefaultIfEmpty and SelectMany to get the equivalent results as your SQL. I prefer the query syntax because it does the SelectMany (which is the "right" way), but reads cleaner.

Comment: you're right it does have  >1 matching rows. Thanks to that, I was able to fix my query. or else, it would have had ended as a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Using DefaultIfEmpty() you can get left outer join result. And taking care of null.

Comment: I've tried that. But I couldn't quite get it right. perhaps you can point out how to actually use it. It would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: This doesn't really add any information. OP is already using `DefaultIfEmpty`.